# tess4j The specified module could not be found

Tags: tess4j

please need your help.. I testing Tess4j but i have a problem

Development environment : eclipse, jdk 1.7

Code

```
System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "32".equals(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")) ? "/lib/win32-x86" : "/lib/win32-x86-64");
    File imgFile = new File("d:\\testImg\\testimg2-1.png");
    System.setProperty("jna.debug_load", "true");
    Tesseract prc = new Tesseract();
    prc.setDatapath("/tessdata");

    try{
        String rslt = prc.doOCR(imgFile);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Error

> Looking in classpath from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93 for /com/sun/jna/win32-x86-64/jnidispatch.dll
>   Found library resource at jar:file:/D:/WorkSpace/sample/lib/jna-4.1.0.jar!/com/sun/jna/win32-x86-64/jnidispatch.dll
>   Looking for library 'libtesseract304'
>   Adding paths from jna.library.path: /lib/win32-x86-64;C:\Users\PANDORA\AppData\Local\Temp\tess4j\win32-x86-64
>   Trying C:\Users\PANDORA\AppData\Local\Temp\tess4j\win32-x86-64\libtesseract304.dll
>   Adding system paths: []
>   Trying C:\Users\PANDORA\AppData\Local\Temp\tess4j\win32-x86-64\libtesseract304.dll
>   Looking for lib- prefix
>   Trying liblibtesseract304.dll
>   Looking in classpath from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93 for libtesseract304
>   Found library resource at jar:file:/D:/WorkSpace/sample/lib/tess4j-3.2.1.jar!/win32-x86-64/libtesseract304.dll
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can not find the specified module
> at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
> at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native.java:1759)
> at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:260)
> at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
> at com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1396)
> at com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1156